# Checking multiple lines and adding a string to the end

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to write a script that will check the contents of /boot/grub/grub.conf for every line that starts with "kernel" and if it doesn't include "nousb" in that line, it will add it to the end.

By default my grub.conf has two lines with kernel, and my script will work the first time and apply "nousb" to the end of both lines. However, to test a scenario where I remove nousb from the first line, and leave it on the second, my script will think it's applied to both lines and not re-apply it to the first one that's missing. Here is what I have

```
grep -w 'nousb' /boot/grub/grub.conf || sudo sed -i '/^\s*kernel/ s/$/ nousb/' /boot/grub/grub.conf
```

I'd like it to add 'nousb' to any line beginning with kernel that's missing it, no matter how many lines have it already. Any thoughts?

Just to showcase, my script above will add nousb to both lines in a file with the following:

```
kernel word1 word2
kernel word3 word4
```

But not this:

```
kernel word1 word2
kernel word3 word4 nousb
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed '/\bkernel\b/{/\bnousb\b/b;s/$/ nousb/}' file
```

> `\b`: marks word boundary
>
> `b`: branch to end of script
>
> `$`: marks end of line

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line ; do
    shopt -s extglob
    if [[ $line == kernel* && $line != *' 'nousb@(' '*|) ]] ; then
        line+=' nousb'
    fi
    printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

The condition checks that `$line` starts with `kernel` plus space and doesn't contain `nousb` preceded by a space and followed by a space or end of line. You can use it to create a new file,  and then replace the old file with it:

```
cp input-file input-file.backup
./script.sh input-file > new-file
mv new-file > input-file
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple with awk:

```
awk '$1=="kernel" && !/\<nousb\>/{$0 = $0 OFS "nousb"} 1' file

kernel word1 word2 nousb
kernel word3 word4 nousb
```

- `$1=="kernel"` checks if first word is `kernel`
- `!/\<nousb\>/` checks if current line doesn't have full word `nosub`
- `$0 = $0 OFS "nousb"` adds `nosub` at the end of current line
- `1` is default action to print each line